# 'Class com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient not found' when installing WWW::HtmlUnit

Tags: linux, perl, ubuntu, htmlunit, cpan

I'm trying to install `WWW::HtmlUnit` for perl in Ubuntu 12.04 64bit. I'm following the directions from the [CPAN page](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aHtmlUnit).

However am getting an error stating that

```
Class com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient not found at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2/Inline/Java.pm line 619.
```

I've pasted my entire log out put for this below. I've seen a few other responses to this question, but were geared towards Windows and not Linux.

```
cpanm (App::cpanminus) 1.5018 on perl 5.014002 built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
Work directory is /home/user/.cpanm/work/1355076552.11533
You have make /usr/bin/make
You have LWP 6.03
You have /bin/tar: tar (GNU tar) 1.26
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by John Gilmore and Jay Fenlason.
You have /usr/bin/unzip
Searching WWW::HtmlUnit on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on WWW::HtmlUnit
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/A/AW/AWWAIID/WWW-HtmlUnit-0.18.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking WWW-HtmlUnit-0.18.tar.gz
Entering WWW-HtmlUnit-0.18
Checking configure dependencies from META.yml
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 0 ... Yes (6.57_05)
Configuring WWW-HtmlUnit-0.18
Running Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Warning: the following files are missing in your kit:
    lib/WWW/HtmlUnit/jar/commons-codec-1.4.jar
    lib/WWW/HtmlUnit/jar/commons-io-2.0.1.jar
    lib/WWW/HtmlUnit/jar/commons-lang-2.6.jar
    lib/WWW/HtmlUnit/jar/cssparser-0.9.5.jar
    lib/WWW/HtmlUnit/jar/htmlunit-2.9.jar
    lib/WWW/HtmlUnit/jar/htmlunit-core-js-2.9.jar
    lib/WWW/HtmlUnit/jar/httpclient-4.1.2.jar
    lib/WWW/HtmlUnit/jar/httpcore-4.1.2.jar
    lib/WWW/HtmlUnit/jar/httpmime-4.1.2.jar
    lib/WWW/HtmlUnit/jar/nekohtml-1.9.15.jar
Please inform the author.
Writing Makefile for WWW::HtmlUnit
Writing MYMETA.yml
-> OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.yml ...
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 0 ... Yes (6.57_05)
Checking if you have Inline::Java 0.53 ... Yes (0.53)
Building and testing WWW-HtmlUnit-0.18
cp lib/WWW/HtmlUnit.pm blib/lib/WWW/HtmlUnit.pm
cp lib/WWW/HtmlUnit/jar/xml-apis-1.3.04.jar blib/lib/WWW/HtmlUnit/jar/xml-apis-1.3.04.jar
cp lib/WWW/HtmlUnit/jar/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar blib/lib/WWW/HtmlUnit/jar/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
cp lib/WWW/HtmlUnit/jar/xalan-2.7.1.jar blib/lib/WWW/HtmlUnit/jar/xalan-2.7.1.jar
cp lib/WWW/HtmlUnit/jar/serializer-2.7.1.jar blib/lib/WWW/HtmlUnit/jar/serializer-2.7.1.jar
cp lib/WWW/HtmlUnit/jar/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar blib/lib/WWW/HtmlUnit/jar/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
cp lib/WWW/HtmlUnit/jar/htmlunit-confirmhandler-2.8.jar blib/lib/WWW/HtmlUnit/jar/htmlunit-confirmhandler-2.8.jar
cp lib/WWW/HtmlUnit/jar/xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar blib/lib/WWW/HtmlUnit/jar/xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar
cp lib/WWW/HtmlUnit/Sweet.pm blib/lib/WWW/HtmlUnit/Sweet.pm
cp lib/WWW/HtmlUnit/jar/sac-1.3.jar blib/lib/WWW/HtmlUnit/jar/sac-1.3.jar
Manifying blib/man3/WWW::HtmlUnit.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/WWW::HtmlUnit::Sweet.3pm
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /usr/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t

#   Failed test 'use WWW::HtmlUnit;'
#   at t/00_basic.t line 9.
#     Tried to use 'WWW::HtmlUnit'.
#     Error:  Class com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient not found at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2/Inline/Java.pm line 619.
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 4) line 2, <GEN7> line 4.
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 1.
t/00_basic.t ......... 
Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/1 subtests 
Class com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient not found at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2/Inline/Java.pm line 619.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/01_hello.t line 4, <GEN7> line 4.
t/01_hello.t ......... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/02_hello_sweet.t ... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
Class com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient not found at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2/Inline/Java.pm line 619.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/03_clickhandler.t line 6, <GEN7> line 4.
# Looks like your test exited with 2 before it could output anything.
t/03_clickhandler.t .. 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
Failed 8/8 subtests 

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/00_basic.t       (Wstat: 256 Tests: 1 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  1
  Non-zero exit status: 1
t/01_hello.t       (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/02_hello_sweet.t (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/03_clickhandler.t (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 8 tests but ran 0.
Files=4, Tests=1,  1 wallclock secs ( 0.04 usr  0.01 sys +  0.58 cusr  0.10 csys =  0.73 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 4/4 test programs. 1/1 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 2
-> FAIL Installing WWW::HtmlUnit failed. See /home/user/.cpanm/build.log for details.
```

Answer (score 1):

Leaving the other answer for posterity, however, the problem is that the author borked the most recent release. As seen in your message, he forgot to include several key files.

```
Warning: the following files are missing in your kit:
    lib/WWW/HtmlUnit/jar/commons-codec-1.4.jar
    lib/WWW/HtmlUnit/jar/commons-io-2.0.1.jar
    lib/WWW/HtmlUnit/jar/commons-lang-2.6.jar
    lib/WWW/HtmlUnit/jar/cssparser-0.9.5.jar
    lib/WWW/HtmlUnit/jar/htmlunit-2.9.jar
    lib/WWW/HtmlUnit/jar/htmlunit-core-js-2.9.jar
    lib/WWW/HtmlUnit/jar/httpclient-4.1.2.jar
    lib/WWW/HtmlUnit/jar/httpcore-4.1.2.jar
    lib/WWW/HtmlUnit/jar/httpmime-4.1.2.jar
    lib/WWW/HtmlUnit/jar/nekohtml-1.9.15.jar
```

This merits a bug ticket (two actually, I found a bug in the classpath code).

For the meantime, you can try installing the old version:

```
cpanm http://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/A/AW/AWWAIID/WWW-HtmlUnit-0.16.tar.gz
```

(using `sudo` and `JAVA_HOME` as needed).

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the [installation instructions](http://search.cpan.org/~awwaiid/WWW-HtmlUnit/lib/WWW/HtmlUnit.pm#INSTALLING)? It looks like [Inline::Java](http://p3rl.org/Inline%3a%3aJava) can't find your java libraries.

You might want to check that you are setting your `JAVA_HOME` to the right path. I believe you can get this by running something like:

```
update-alternatives --query java | perl -ne 'print if s/Value: //'
```

For me this gives:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/java
```

but you don't want the bin part so I would use

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
```

Edit: didn't want `/jre` either

Comment: Followed install instructions, and did your recommendation, but still same issue. Set the /etc/environment for JAVA_HOME to /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre and re-ran the install, still same error message.

Comment: The [CPANTesters](http://www.cpantesters.org/distro/W/WWW-HtmlUnit.html#WWW-HtmlUnit-0.18) are having troubles too. Perhaps this module does not install well.

Comment: I am trying to install myself, I noticed that my JAVA_HOME wasn't right either, edited to reflect